# Is there a better way to evaluate user inputs without a 'for' loop and changing a checker from False to True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to python and have been, as an exercise, doing a text-based version of a board game (I'm an avid board gamer).

There are obviously lots of places for the user to input something, and naturally I need to evaluate those inputs and make sure they are valid.

I learned about using a True/False check and for loops from this site (thanks!) and now that I've done them so much I was wondering if there was a better way - they get a little crazy if they are nested and I want to to my best to adhere to those Zen-like Python rules.

Here is what I mean, in a simple example, using generic code so it makes sense (not all of you may know the rules of this board game!)

The goal is to make sure the code loops until a color or "none" is given. I know this accomplishes that, i'm just wondering if there is a more streamlined way that I haven't learned yet.

```
colors = ["red", "green", "white", "blue", "yellow"]

for color in colors:
    print(f"You can choose {color}.")

choice = input("Which color would you choose? (input a color or 'none' : ")
checker = False

while not checker:
    if choice not in colors:
        choice = input("That's not one of your options. Choose again: ")

    elif choice == "none":
        print("You don't want a color. That's fine.")
        checker = True

    else:
        print("You chose {color}! Have fun!")
        checker = True
```

Comment: this looks reasonable ...

Comment: Think about a full-blown argument parser like `argparse` or `click` - they don't need to be used on the *program*'s command-line argument. Even if you don't actually use one of them, the mindset may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a generic function if you find yourself repeating the same things

```
def prompt_for_valid_input(options):
    while True:
        print(f"You can choose one of {options}.")
        choice = input("Which would you choose? (or 'none' : ")
        if choice == "none" and "none" not in options:
            print("You didn't pick anything. That's fine.")
            return None
        elif choice in options:
            return choice
        else:
            print("That's not one of your options. Choose again. ")

colors = ["red", "green", "white", "blue", "yellow"]
color = prompt_for_valid_input(colors)
if color is not None:
    print(f"You chose {color}! Have fun!")

numbers = [1, 10, 100]
num = prompt_for_valid_input(numbers)
if num is not None:
    print(f"You chose {num}! Have fun!")
```

So "without a while/for loop", not really. Without a sentinel variable, yes, if the conditions are simple enough.

Comment: Thanks for this, I like this idea.

In my code, often times entering a certain input launches a function which itself might have more input validators. I like this idea and can probably implement it wisely in the right spots.

Answer (score 0):

you can abstract it out to a generic validated input method

```
def validated_input(prompt,validation_method,error_message):
    while True:
         result = input(prompt)
         if validation_method(result):
            return result
         print(error_message)


choices = ['red','green','blue','none']
validator = lambda test:test.lower().strip() in choices
prompt = "Enter A Color(one of Red, Green, Blue, or None):"
error_message = "Please enter a valid color or None!"

print(validated_input(prompt,validator,error_message))
```

**its arguable whether this is "better"**

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I see now how a function like this can actually help me a lot. Often my validations lead to a function, and sometimes those have more validations. I'll play with these kind of constructions and see if i can improve the code!

Answer (score 0):

Usually how you wrote your code is considered pretty "normal" and straightforward which is good. The issue is that you would want the looping part of your code to repeat till it has met its expectation. So a conditional looping event is necessary. If you really want you can simplify it a little by making a break statement for example:

```
x = 0
while True:
  if x == 12:
     break;
  else:
     x = x + 1
print(x)
```

This will create a infinite loop until the condition you are looking for is met and then it will break out of the loop. Make sure you have your escape condition though.